# Find file and return full path using a batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, directory

Is it possible to create a batch file that searches for a file name, then returns its path so I can use it in a variable?

Comment: Check this to get the solution   [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414715/a-bat-or-wsh-script-that-can-search-for-files)

Answer (score 21):

```
for /r C:\folder %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="file.txt" set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
echo %p%
) else (
echo File not found
)
```

If the file you searched for was found it will set the variable `%p%` to the full path of the file including name and extension.

If you just want the path (as in the folder path without the file) then use `set p=%%~dpa` instead.

***Note***: If there is more than 1 file with the same name then the variable will be set to the last one found. Also the script after the `for` loop line isn't really necessary, just to show you if it found anything :)

If you want to do it using the `dir` command then use this, same rules apply

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir acad.exe /b /s') do set p=%%a
```

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of 'find acad.exe /b /s' however I cant get this into a text file or variable...

Comment: What do you mean? The `dir` command would have to be run in a `for` loop anyways, why not just run the `for` loop?

Comment: I have added another option in my answer to use a `dir` command, more similar to what you wanted :)

Comment: looping through all the files is not good, especially if the folder contains millions of files. Just use `dir /b /s filename`

Answer (score 5):

Do this: -

`for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "C:\File.txt" 2^>nul') do set MyVariable=%%F`

Assuming you are searching `C` drive for `File.txt` .

Comment: TBH i didn't really understand any of the two answers, but this one looked like it also works with wildcards (i do not know that the other one doesn't!) so it tried it and it worked.

Comment: This doesn't really do much of a search, you have to know the file and what directory it's in, which isn't what the OP asked for.