# Find absolute path of Rscript batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a small script to find the absolute path of *Rscript* in a machine running Windows OS. I assume that *Rscript* must be found under *C:\Program Files\R\R-x.x.x* directory, where x.x.x represents any version of R. I have written the following script based on several threads ([Find file and return full path using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876771/find-file-and-return-full-path-using-a-batch-file)).

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /d %%a in ("C:\Program Files\R\") do (
  if "%%~nxa"=="Rscript.exe" (
    set p=%%~dpnxa
    )
)
```

Unfortunately, the *if* condition assigns *p* to every file and folder in *C:\Program Files\R\R-x.x.x*. If anyone has any idea of how to find and assign *p* properly, I would really appreciate it!

Regards,

Juan

**EDIT**

I'm adding my full script

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /R %%a in ("C:\Program Files\R\R-*") do (
  if /i "%%~nxa"=="Rscript.exe" (
    set "p=%%~fa"
    )
)
if defined p (
echo %p%
) else (
echo File not found
)

%p% runShinyApp.R 1> ShinyApp.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Put `R-*` behind `\R\ `and replace `if "%%~nxa"=="Rscript.exe"` by `if exist "%%~fa\Rscript.exe", then use `set "p=%%~fa\Rscript.exe"`…

Comment: I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do `%%~dpnxa` when you can just do `%%~fa` anyway, here are some ways.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("C:\Program Files\R\*") do (
  if /i "%%~nxa"=="Rscript.exe" (
    set "p=%%~fa"
    )
)
```

another method is to use `where`, without having to do an `if` statement, simply because you specify the executable in the `where` search. You can recursively search for the path in an entire drive, or specify a path, here for instance we recursively search in `"C:\Program Files"`.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r "%programfiles%" "rscript.exe"2^>nul') do set "p=%%~fa"
```

*EDIT* after your comments, this should work.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r "%programfiles%\R\R-3.6.3\bin\x64" "rscript.exe"2^>nul') do "%%~fa" runShinyApp.R 1> ShinyApp.log
```

I would however recommend you specify the path to `runShinyApp.R` in the `do` line.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However, I cannot find any of the *Rscript.exe* files available in my *R-x.x.x* folder (I have 3 different files under  *R-x.x.x\bin*,  *R-x.x.x\bin\x64* and  *R-x.x.x\bin\x386* directories.

Comment: then you must find it. open `cmd` and run `where /R c:\ "rscript.exe"` and show me the result.

Comment: I get what I was expecting `c:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\Rscript.exe
c:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe
c:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe`

Comment: ok, good, so which one of those would you like to use to execute? `x64`, `i386` or directly in `bin`? I will then amend my answer

Comment: The one in `x64`

Comment: See bottom script in my answer, copy as is please.