# Batch script to search for all files starting with 00_ 01_ (and so on)

Tags: batch-file, search

is there any kind of batch script to search for all files on a drive starting with '##_', while ## stands for 00, 01, 02, till 99? After the search a list with the full path of the files should be displayed or at least created.

Example of a file name: 12_06_03-13_03_14.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414715/a-bat-or-wsh-script-that-can-search-for-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A .bat or .wsh script that can search for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414715/a-bat-or-wsh-script-that-can-search-for-files)

Comment: Yes there are such code.

Comment: @SteveFest, do you know how such a code looks like?

Comment: Yes I do. I know how they look like.

Comment: @SteveFest, would you be so kind and tell me the code please?

Comment: I'd wish I could...

Comment: A nice user was so kind and send me the code :)
Problem solved