# Batch File progress spinning wheel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have been trying for days and can seem to get this to work. I found an example but it uses a (CryEcho) which will not work. I just wanted to add this to let the user know something is going on while im pinging IP addresses. I did find some code on here but it was confusing to me since im just starting to mess around with batch files for fun.

Anyway, I wanted to have something that used something like the example below but with text like (Waiting...[spinner]). Thanks!

```
@echo off
setlocal

set COUNT=0
set MAXCOUNT=10
set SECONDS=1

:LOOP
title "\"
call :WAIT
title "|"
call :WAIT
title "/"
call :WAIT
title "-"
if /i "%COUNT%" equ "%MAXCOUNT%" goto :EXIT
set /a count+=1
echo %COUNT%
goto :LOOP

:WAIT
ping -n %SECONDS% 127.0.0.1 > nul
ping -n %SECONDS% 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto :EOF

:EXIT
title FIN!
endlocal
```

AND I found this code as well:

```
@echo off
rem Example showing how to use CryEcho to produce a spinning wheel to show activity.

CryEcho Working ... 
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork
call :SpinAlive
call :DoSomeWork

cryecho \s\nFinished.

goto :eof

:DoSomeWork
ping -n 1 localhost > nul
goto :eof

:SpinAlive
if "%Spinner%" == "2" (cryecho \\\b) 
if "%Spinner%" == "3" (cryecho -q "|"\b) 
if "%Spinner%" == "4" (cryecho /\b set Spinner=0) else (cryecho -\b set Spinner=1)
set /A Spinner=%Spinner%+1
goto :eof
```

Comment: I guess this comes down to being able to output a sole carriage-return (without the line feed), which I think is not possible in pure batch without external tools.

Comment: @Joey All is possible :-) Nearly every character can be created in batch with `forfiles`,`copy` and `prompt`

Comment: [Very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/368041/218597), tho' @jeb's answer is a little neater, IMO.

Comment: @icabod Yes paxdiabolo uses a `backspace`, but I don't like to embedd a control character into the batch file, as you need a special editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CALL :BACKSPACE $BS
SET /A FULL_COUNT=75
SET /A MAX_COUNT=160
SET /A Spin_Delay=60
SET "_MSG=Process running..."
SET /A CTR=0
IF NOT [%1]==[] SET "_MSG=%~1"
IF NOT [%2]==[] SET /A FULL_COUNT=%2
IF NOT [%3]==[] SET /A SPIN_DELAY=%3
IF %FULL_COUNT% GTR %MAX_COUNT% SET /A FULL_COUNT=%MAX_COUNT%
<nul SET/P="%_MSG%*"
SET "SPINNER=³/Ä\"
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%FULL_COUNT%) DO (
  CALL :DELAY %SPIN_DELAY%
  <nul CALL SET/P="%$BS%%%SPINNER:~!CTR!,1%%"
  SET /A CTR=%%A %% 4
)
<nul SET/P="%$BS%*"
ENDLOCAL & EXIT /B %CTR%

:BackSpace
setlocal
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
endlocal&call set %~1=%BS%&exit /b 0

:Delay msec
setlocal
set/a correct=0
set/a msecs=%1+5
if /i %msecs% leq 20 set /a correct-=2
set time1=%time: =%
set/a tsecs=%1/1000 2>nul
set/a msecs=(%msecs% %% 1000)/10
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%a in ("%time1%") do (
  set hour1=%%a&set min1=%%b&set sec1=%%c&set "mil1=%%d"
)
if /i %hour1:~0,1% equ 0 if /i "%hour1:~1%" neq "" set hour1=%hour1:~1%
if /i %min1:~0,1% equ 0 set min1=%min1:~1% 
if /i %sec1:~0,1% equ 0 set sec1=%sec1:~1%
if /i %mil1:~0,1% equ 0 set mil1=%mil1:~1% 
set/a sec1+=(%hour1%*3600)+(%min1%*60)
set/a msecs+=%mil1%
set/a tsecs+=(%sec1%+%msecs%/100)
set/a msecs=%msecs% %% 100
::    check for midnight crossing
if /i %tsecs% geq 86400 set /a tsecs-=86400
set/a hour2=%tsecs% / 3600
set/a min2=(%tsecs%-(%hour2%*3600)) / 60
set/a sec2=(%tsecs%-(%hour2%*3600)) %% 60
set/a err=%msecs%
if /i %msecs% neq 0 set /a msecs+=%correct%
if /i 1%msecs% lss 20 set "msecs=0%msecs%"
if /i 1%min2% lss 20 set "min2=0%min2%"
if /i 1%sec2% lss 20 set "sec2=0%sec2%"
set "time2=%hour2%:%min2%:%sec2%.%msecs%"
:wait
  set timen=%time: =%
  if /i %timen% geq %time2% goto :end
goto :wait
:end
for /f "tokens=2 delims=." %%a in ("%timen%") do set num=%%a
if /i %num:~0,1% equ 0 set num=%num:~1%
set/a err=(%num%-%err%)*10
endlocal&exit /b %err%
```

Comment: `SET "SPINNER=³/Ä\"` isn't correct. And why are you doing a lot of things while he only needs a spinning wheel? A code-only result isn't suitable here. Some explanation and comment would help

Answer (score 10):

The main trick is here to move the cursor back on the same line.
This can be done with a `carriage return` or a `backspace` characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

FOR /L %%n in (1,1,10) DO (
    call :spinner
    ping localhost -n 2 > nul
)
exit /b

:spinner
set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
set "spinChars=\|/-"
<nul set /p ".=Waiting !spinChars:~%spinner%,1!!CR!"
exit /b
```

The `<CR>` character is created from the output of `copy /z`.
The output is done by `set /p`, as this omits the output of `CR/LF` at the end.
The `!CR!` is output each time to force the cursor to move back to the first column.
But as Win7 and Vista removes all whitespaces and also `CR` from the leading output of `set /p`, it's placed at the end.

Comment: Nice solution, but on WinXP this outputs `/W` for the `/`, I guess due to the fix for Win7/Vista. A solution (for XP) is to make the set: `=!CR!W!CR!Waiting !spinChars:~%spinner%,1!". Not tried that in Vista/Win7 mind.

Comment: Thanks, a few questions though. Why does it look like (Waiting /|\W) with a "W" at the end? Also, is the (1,1,10) how many times it spins?

Comment: @icabod I fixed the output, @user1875160 `(1,1,10)` lets the `FOR/L` loop count from 1 to 10

Comment: icabod, One more question, How can I incorporate this into a menu? I have a menu with 9 choice with goto. Would I have to put the code in each GOTO to show the waiting spinner or can I call the spinner. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: @user1875160: You're better off asking jeb, as he posted the answer :)