# Batch file progress percentage

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I show the progress of a long running operation in windows batch (cmd) file in percentage? Can you share some example code?

Comment: Depends specifically on what the operation is ...

Comment: Yes agreed. It should be easy if you can break down your operation into discrete steps. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how...

Note: This code is a slightly modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14712623/39648) answer.

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

FOR /L %%n in (1,1,10) DO (
    call :show_progress %%n 10
    ping localhost -n 2 > nul
)

echo Done!
exit /b

:show_progress
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set current_step=%1
set total_steps=%2
set /a "progress=(current_step * 100) / total_steps"

set /p ".=Progress: !progress!%%!CR!" <nul

if !progress! equ 100 echo.

exit /b
```

Comment: I recommend to state `if !progress! EQU 100` to do a true numeric comparison as `==` forces string comparison...

Comment: Just saying it is good coding practice to match every `setlocal` with an `endlocal` for readability.  @SandeepDatta that is a interesting that `!cr!`puts the carriage return stored in variable into the output stream but  `%cr%` does not. Do you know why the latter does not work?

Comment: @SkipR See following link for an explanation of why sometimes ! is needed instead of %: http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Changing code to `set /p ".=Progress: %progress%%%!CR!" <nul` and `if %progress% equ 100 echo.` makes no difference - I think it is clearer to only use delayed expansion syntax only when it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

An example would be scanning a large file/database, showing progress instead of a blinking cursor, for ages!

```
set c=<no. of lines in file>
for /l %i in (1,1,%c%) do cls & set /p="Scanning for target ... "<nul & (set /a per=%i00/%c% >nul & echo !per!%)& ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul & REM when target found, send agents to greet
echo Complete.
```

The code in brackets `()` are for progress percentage.

Tested in Win 10 CmD>

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('find /v /c "" ^< %1') do (SET rows=%%g)
echo:
set /A target=%rows%/10
set /A percent=0
set /A line=0
for /F %%a in (%~n1%~x1) do ( 
  set /A line+=1
  SET /A mod = !line! %% !target!
  if !mod! == 0 (
                set /A percent+=10
                echo !percent!^%% at !TIME:~0,8!
                )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).