# TFS Get File Running Progress in Percentage

Tags: c#, winforms, tfs

I am downloading the branch from TFS using the below code :-

```
        TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("URL", System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
        // tfs server url including the  Collection Name --  CollectionName as the existing name of the collection from the tfs server 
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

        VersionControlServer sourceControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

        Workspace[] workspaces = sourceControl.QueryWorkspaces(workspaceName, sourceControl.AuthenticatedUser, Workstation.Current.Name);
        if (workspaces.Length > 0)
        {
            sourceControl.DeleteWorkspace(workspaceName, sourceControl.AuthenticatedUser);
        }
        Workspace workspace = sourceControl.CreateWorkspace(workspaceName, sourceControl.AuthenticatedUser, "Temporary Workspace");
        try
        {
            workspace.Map(projectPath, workingDirectory);
            GetRequest request = new GetRequest(new ItemSpec(projectPath, RecursionType.Full), VersionSpec.Latest);
            GetStatus status = workspace.Get(request, GetOptions.GetAll | GetOptions.Overwrite); // this line gets the status of request

        }
        finally
        {
            if (workspace != null)
            {
                workspace.Delete();

            }
        }
```

I want to show the status in ProgressBar but not able to do it. I am even using BackGroundWorker tool. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such TFS API can achieve what you need.

As a work around, you can try to use the Progress Indicators in a Windows PowerShell script or a windows batch (cmd) file.

- Powershell script: [Using Progress Indicators in Windows
  PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/b8a57917-f6fe-4110-b2d3-1860dc51efbf)
- Windows batch (cmd) file:
  [Batch file progress percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281337/batch-file-progress-percentage)