# Display output in a certain way using echo of batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working on a program using batch where the program read root directories from a text file and count total number of **Folders** and **Files** in all th give root directories. The program is working as it should be but I want to display the output in a certain way.

This is how I want to display output

[image]

**0 : OF : 6**

The first value should change each time program finish counting in one root directory. I have written code for it but the output I am getting is this.

[image]

Here is code I have written to change it.

```
:textUpdate
echo !counter! : OF : %number%
GOTO :EOF
```

where **counter** is the current number of root directory and **number** is total number of directories found in the text file. Is there any way to display the output like the first one.

Comment: Where do u change the `number` variable

Comment: @Monacraft number variable is defined when I collect total number of directories in a given file and counter is incremented every time a directory files and folder count is finished.

Comment: When you say root directory count, do you mean you are performing the routine on each volume/partition? _(There is only one root directory in each)_. Either way, if you're doing a number `x` of `y` you first need to count them all so that you know the value of `y`. What method are you using for that? _Please provide the code..._

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to code a spinner for waiting processes in a Batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368041/how-to-code-a-spinner-for-waiting-processes-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can abuse `set /p` to write to screen. It doens't append a line feed. You also need a Carriage Return to go back to the beginning of the line to overwrite the old output:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
for /l %%n in (1,1,6) do (
    set /P "=Count %%n of 6!CR!" <nul
    timeout 1 >nul
)
```

The first `for /f` loop is just to get a `CR` (Carriage Return). You have to use delayed expansion to be able to use it (`%CR%` does not work).